# Mongoexport date range query result in Failure parsing

Tags: mongodb, mongoexport

Trying to run mongoexport and having problems with my query parameter.

```
mongoexport -d test-copy  -c collection -o /home/ubuntu/mongodb-archiving/mongodump/collection.json --query '{"created_at": {\$lte: new Date(1451577599000) } }'
```

Collection is:

`{"created_at" : ISODate("2014-03-07T06:32:19.172Z")}`

To which I can query just fine in Mongo Client.

The result in the following error:

> Assertion: 10340:Failure parsing JSON string near: "created_a

Comment: I dont think u can specify date in `mongoexport` command. I've solved: open shell command, query with date parameter and save it into collection2. Then export collection2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `\` in your query. Please remove it.

```
--query '{"created_at": {$lte: new Date(1451577599000)}}'
```

Comment: Is it using Unix timestamp?

Answer (score 2):

You should use $date with mongoexport:

```
mongoexport.exe -h *HOST* -p *PORT* -q "{ 'created_at' : { '$lt' : { '$date' : '2014-03-07T06:32:19.172Z' } } }"
```

Comment: No error was raised but no records was also exported.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `\$lte`  and change it to quoted `"$lt"` in your query, and the mongodump shall work fine.
Tested on mongodb 3.0.8

```
> use appdb
> db.testcoll.find({})
{ "_id" : 1, "created_at" : ISODate("2016-09-15T08:46:12.272Z") }
{ "_id" : 2, "created_at" : ISODate("2016-09-15T08:46:12.272Z") }
{ "_id" : 3, "created_at" : ISODate("2016-09-16T08:46:30.736Z") }
{ "_id" : 4, "created_at" : ISODate("2016-09-16T08:47:12.368Z") }
{ "_id" : 5, "created_at" : ISODate("2016-09-16T08:47:15.562Z") }

> db.testcoll.find({"created_at":{"$lt":new Date("2016-09-16")}})

{ "_id" : 1, "created_at" : ISODate("2016-09-15T08:46:12.272Z") }
{ "_id" : 2, "created_at" : ISODate("2016-09-15T08:46:12.272Z") }

> db.testcoll.find({"created_at":{"$lt":new Date(1473984000)}})

  // make sure you are using millisecond version of epoch
> db.testcoll.find({"created_at":{"$lt":new Date(1473984000000)}})

{ "_id" : 1, "created_at" : ISODate("2016-09-15T08:46:12.272Z") }
{ "_id" : 2, "created_at" : ISODate("2016-09-15T08:46:12.272Z") }
```

Now the mongodump part :

```
dp@xyz:~$ mongodump -d appdb -c testcoll --query '{"created_at":{"$lt":new Date(1473984000000)}}'
2016-09-16T14:21:27.695+0530    writing appdb.testcoll to dump/appdb/testcoll.bson
2016-09-16T14:21:27.696+0530    writing appdb.testcoll metadata to dump/appdb/testcoll.metadata.json
2016-09-16T14:21:27.708+0530    done dumping appdb.testcoll (2 documents)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `mongoexport` and `mongodump` tools require a valid JSON object for the `--query` parameter. From https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/#cmdoption--query:

> --query , -q
>
> Provides a JSON document as a query that optionally limits the documents included in the output of mongodump.
>
> You must enclose the query in single quotes (e.g. ') to ensure that it does not interact with your shell environment.

The command failed due to the query parameter you passed into `mongoexport`, which is not a valid JSON object due to the existence of `new Date()` which is a Javascript statement.

The required modification is to simply use the example `ISODate()` object you provided, .e.g:

```
mongoexport -d test-copy  -c collection -o /home/ubuntu/mongodb-archiving/mongodump/collection.json --query '{"created_at": {$lte: ISODate("2014-03-07T06:32:19.172Z") } }'
```

You just need to replace the contents of the `ISODate()` with the date you require.

Comment: Used this `--query '{ "created_at": {$lte: ISODate("2015-11-31T23:59:59.599Z" } }'` and got `Sun Sep 18 16:27:43 Assertion: 10340:Failure parsing JSON string near: "created_a`

Comment: What is your MongoDB version? Could you try running `mongoexport --version`? I used this command in MongoDB 3.2.9 and it works as expected: `mongoexport -d test -c test --query '{created_at:{$lte:ISODate("2016-09-19T00:00:00Z")}}'`

Comment: Using version 2.0.4

Comment: That explains why your command doesn't work. I believe MongoDB 2.0 version of `mongoexport` only supports simple JSON documents in the `--query` parameter (e.g. it doesn't support the `$lte` operator). MongoDB 2.0.x end-of-life was March 2013, so if possible, I would suggest to upgrade to the latest version (currently 3.2.9) which can do the `ISODate` query you need.

Comment: Thanks @KevinAdistambha, at the moment we can't upgrade to the latest versionn. Instead will resolve to using the `new Date()` Javascript method.